# Pycharm showing two different Working Directories at the same time

Tags: pycharm

I am using Pycharm 2023.2 Community Edition.
I am currently debugging a file in directory example.

Pycharm seems to giving me two different working directories?

File -> Settings -> Project Structure: lists the working directory as /baz/pych/mom

However

Run -> Edit Configurations lists the working directory as /baz/pych/mom/example

Will having different Working Directories like this cause a problem?

How can I set the working directory I want?

Answer (score 1):

The File -> Settings -> Project Structure section shows the *content root* (of which you can have multiple), not (necessarily) the same as any particular working directory.

Among the run configurations you have you can customize whatever you like.
It can be different for different run configurations.
Perhaps you have a documentation build that must run from path/docs, perhaps you have an tutorial example that needs to run from path/examples.

In addition, for each run configuration you also find two checkboxes:

```
[x] Add content roots to PYTHONPATH
[x] Add source roots to PYTHONPATH
```

both of which are typically selected. So here you see how the content roots you selected in the settings come into play.

In summary; no, pycharm isn't even showing two *working* directories at the same time here. And for any given program being run, it will only have one particular working directory, the one you select for that particular run configuration. You are free to choose whatever is correct for your application when you set up your run configurations.

Comment: If the content path is set by File -> ... then am I right to assume that source roots is set by Run -> ...? [x] Add content roots to PYTHONPATH and [x] Add source roots to PYTHONPATH are both selected does this mean I should be able to find a file via a relative file paths from both of these? Because at the moment it seems to only be relative to /baz/pych/mom/example which is the source roots path.

Comment: These are added to `PYTHONPATH`, which is independent of the *single* working directory your script will have. Adding things to PYTHONPATH means python will look there when you `import foo`. It of course doesn't affect `open(filename)` or anything like that.